# Overpass query works on overpass-turbo.eu, but not locally

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to execute Overpass queries from a Python script. I'm practicing at overpass-turbo.eu and found the following query to work as intended:

```
[out:json][timeout:600];
{{geocodeArea:Niedersachsen}}->.searchArea;
(
  node[place=city](area.searchArea);  
  node[place=town](area.searchArea);  

);
out;
```

However, when I submit the exact same query from a Python script, I get an error:

```
import requests
overpass_query = """
[out:json][timeout:600];
{{geocodeArea:Niedersachsen}}->.searchArea;
(
  node[place=city](area.searchArea);  
  node[place=town](area.searchArea);  

);
out;
"""
overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': overpass_query})
data = response.json()

/home/enno/events/docker/etl/venv/bin/python /home/enno/events/docker/etl/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/enno/events/docker/etl/test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    data = response.json()
  File "/home/enno/events/docker/etl/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is this? It seems to have to do with the curly braces, but I can't figure out how to solve this.

Many thanks,

Enno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces (aka `{{geocodeArea:Niedersachsen}}`) are a special feature of overpass turbo and are not part of Overpass API. See [extended overpass turbo queries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Extended_Overpass_Turbo_Queries) for a list of these shortcuts.

`{{geocodeArea:name}}` will tell overpass turbo to perform a geocoding request using [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). It will then use the first result to construct an `area(id)` query. You have to perform the same step (using Nominatim or any other [geocoder](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines)) in your program.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now!

Comment: hello Scai hello mcenno - to get the fully understanding: The curly braces (aka {{geocodeArea:Niedersachsen}}) are a special feature of overpass turbo - so they work in Overpass-Turbo (eg at the webfrontend ) but if we perform a request to the endpoint of  the overpass-api - then we need to use other nomination (nominatim) to succeed!? - If so - if i got you both right - then many  thanks. I am currently tryin to extend my insights in all that.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. overpass turbo uses Nominatim to convert the named area to a polygon. You will have to do the same if you want to use named areas directly with Overpass API (i.e. without the overpass turbo frontend). Alternatively you can try to query for the area by tags. For the above case the following should work: `relation["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="4"]["name"="Niedersachsen"];`.